# How to retrieve a word from the string

Tags: javascript

```
str = <a href = "#homecoupon" class ="current">COUPONS</a>
```

how to get the word COUPONS from the str. the word #homecoupon might change to other word so i can't do the substring method of retrieving the nth position value. the `class ="current">COUPONS</a>` will always be fixed.

Is there a way i can back track and retrieve the last nth word.

Comment: Are you scraping a website or is this part of your website?

Comment: both answers will work for you, just remember to single quote that line and add ad semicolon at the end. Otherwise there's no way in hell it will be valid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

**The best way to parse HTML in the browser is to let the browser do it for you.**

Create a dummy element in memory, then set its `innerHTML` to your string. You can then use the regular DOM API to find the text of that anchor element:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var word = div.firstChild.textContent;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mREFu/

---

If you still have to support IE < 9, you'll have to use this:

```
var word = div.firstChild.textContent || div.firstChild.innerText;
```

Or you could get the text from the text node:

```
var word = div.firstChild.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Comment: +1 but you should really add an explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an actual string not a part of a web page :

```
var str = '<a href = "#homecoupon" class ="current">COUPONS</a>';

var word = str.match(/"current">(.*?)</);
if(word) word = word[1]; //== COUPONS
```

Or if you're using jQuery and that's an actual web page you can go :

```
$('a.current').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `substring()` and `indexof()` you can do this.

```
str = '<a href = "#homecoupon" class ="current">COUPONS</a>';

// get rid of </a> assuming the string always ends with it
var x = str.substring(0,str.length-4);

// use the fixed part to get the value you want
alert(x.substring(x.indexOf('class ="current">')+17))
```

OR

```
str = '<a href = "#homecoupon" class ="current">COUPONS</a>';
fixedPart = 'class ="current">';

// use the fixed part to get the value you want assuming str always ends with </a>
alert(str.substring(str.indexOf(fixedPart)+fixedPart.length, str.length-4))
```